# Build MILP constraint from if-else statements

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I need to build a MILP (Mixed integer linear programming) constraint form this if-else statement:
with beta is a constant.

```
if (a > b) then c = beta else c = 0
```

How can I build the statement to MILP constraint. Are there any techniques for solving this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

I am assuming that `a`, `b`, and `c` are all decision variables here. To build your constraint, you need to add a new binary variable -- let's call it `x` -- that will equal 1 if `a > b` and 0 otherwise. You also need a large constant `M`. Then add the following constraints:

```
Mx >= a - b
M(1-x) >= b - a
x in {0,1}
```

The logic is: If `a > b`, then `x` must equal 1 by the first constraint (and `x` *may* equal 1 by the second constraint). If `b > a`, then `1-x` must equal 1 by the second constraint, i.e., `x` must equal 0 (and `x` *may* equal 0 by the first constraint).

Next, we need a constraint that says, if `x = 1`, then `c = beta`, otherwise, `c = 0`:

```
c = beta * x
```

*Note*: The logic above allows `c` to equal either 0 or beta if `a = b`; the solver will decide. Do you need `c` to equal 0 if `a = b`?

*Another note*: In "big-`M`"-type formulations like this one, it's always best to keep `M` as small as possible while maintaining the validity of the constraints. In this case, this means setting `M` to the largest possible (or plausible) difference between `a` and `b`. If your model is small, it won't matter much, but if you have lots of these decision variables, then it can matter a lot.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Sure thing. FYI, there's lots more on optimization and modeling on the new [or.se] Stack.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to do it as a single constraint:

- Let c be binary. The contrapositive of "if (a > b) then c = 1 else c = 0" is "if c = 0 then a <= b".
- This contrapositive can be implemented using big-M as a <= b + M * c

You can then scale the binary c to get what you want.