# Create/optimize model for assignment problem

Tags: modeling, or-tools, cp-sat

Asked also here https://groups.google.com/g/or-tools-discuss/c/AmLY-SRidn0 in case it gets solved look for both places.

I am trying to solve an assignment problem with Google OR-Tools, but I was hitting pretty fast way too high numbers.

I am trying to model for schools. They are mostly like normal schools (one teacher can only be asigned once for one hour and similar things). The biggest difference is: "two or more courses can be taught together, if they share the same lesson".

My first approach was to gather whatever I need: lessons, rooms, teachers, courses and times.
Then I put them in a table which would later become my matrix. My sketch looks like this.
[image: Matrix sketch]
The main problem are the times since theres a lot of them. There are 10-20 time slots for every day and I am trying to calculate for months. In my first example I got 1500 timeslots, 1 course, 450 lessons, 23 rooms, 46 teachers. That's pretty close to a real world scenario (except from the 1 course). This creates more than 700 million entries for my matrix.

I was able to test that on big hardware. Creating the matrix via `IntVar[,] x = solver.MakeBoolVarMatrix(rows, cols, "x");`used up around 200gb of RAM.
A few hours later the first set of constraints is not finished creating.

The first set of constraints being:

```
for (int r = 0; r < roomscount; r++)
{
    for (int t = 0; t < timescount; t++)
    {
        List<IntExpr> result = new List<IntExpr>();
        for (int f = 0; f < teacherscount; f++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < coursescount; k++)
            {
                var intermediate_result = (from i in Enumerable.Range((f * roomscount * lessonscount) + (r * coursescount), lessonscount) select AllCourseNumbers[k] * x[i, k * timescount + t]).ToArray();
                result.AddRange(intermediate_result);
            }
        }
        solver.Add(result.ToArray().Sum() <= roomsCapacity[r]);
    }
}
```

Here I am trying to do for each "room and time combination" I am searching for all teachers and courses and add up these courses. This way I can ensure the capacity of a room is not exceeded.

I also made a target function (don't know if it's the correct term, that's what I am trying to minimize). The target is to teach multiple courses as often as possible, so I have more rooms and teachers available for even more courses, or to substitue a teacher if necessary.

My goal is to add up every combination where teacher, room, lesson and time slot are the same for every course. When this sum is bigger than > 0 I want to add 1 in the final result, if nothing is selected I add nothing to the final result. This way everytime two or more courses are put together the final result shrinks 1 or more points down.

I create an array that contains all those combinations as IntExpr objects.
Then I do an if-then simulation (idea taken from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/55903389)

```
//big constant M
int M = 1 + allCoursesCount
//new binary variable to simulate min(1,oneOfTheSums)
IntVar[] b = solver.MakeBoolVarArray(teacher_room_lesson_timeslots_combinations);
//constraint for new binary variable
for (int i = 0; i <  teacher_room_lesson_timeslots_combinations  ; i++)
{
    solver.Add(M * b[i] >= ListOfSums[i]);
    solver.Add(M * (1 - b[i]) > -1 * ListOfSums[i]);
}
```

In the end i can sum over b to get exactly what I wanted. A sum of how often a room (and a teacher for the room) are selected.

As I said it got really big really fast.

Is there a way to simplify the whole model? Do I need terrabytes of RAM? I am not really sure how I should go on from here.

Thanks in advance